# Make first row of table all bold

Tags: tables, formatting, bold

I'm trying to do something that I thought would be relatively simple but seems to be quite hard. I have a table with a number of columns, and I'd like to make all of the titles appear in bold text. Obviously I can add `\textbf` to each of them in turn, but it strikes me that there must be a nicer way of doing this (particularly for tables with many columns).

As far as I can see there isn't a good way of doing this with plain LaTeX. Are there any packages that make this (and possibly other table-related issues) easier?

Comment: Check this page: [How to change a whole row of a table](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=wholerow). It shows how to change the style of a whole row by using package array.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Taking apan's comment and turning it into an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{$}{>{\global\let\currentrowstyle\relax}}
\newcolumntype{^}{>{\currentrowstyle}}
\newcommand{\rowstyle}[1]{\gdef\currentrowstyle{#1}%
  #1\ignorespaces
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{$l^c^r}
\rowstyle{\bfseries}
a & a & a \\
b & b & b \\
c & c & c \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

This gives:

[image]

You might, of course, choose different markers for the column types.

---

To explain what is going on, the first 'column' is of type `$` (could be any symbol not required in the preamble). This simply sets `\currentrowstyle` to do nothing, which means that in each row this command will be a no-op unless something else happens. The first *real* column (here `l`) will contain the command to make it bold (if required), but that is not true for the other columns. They therefore are preceded by `^`, which is another fake column type used to apply `\currentrowstyle`.

In a normal row, `\currentrowstyle` therefore starts off as `\relax` and never changes, so the `^` do nothing and the row is unchanged. However, if the first column sets `\rowstyle`, this is saved as `\currentrowstyle` (for the later columns) and applied (for this column). The `^` then insert this at the start of each column in the row, so everything is bold.

(All of the operations are global as table cells form groups.)

Comment: I think I can explain how this works: `$` is defined to "reset" the comment \currentrowstyle which is defined in  \rowstyle. the rowstly command also sets the style for the column is currently is in (that's what the second #1 is for). The ^ simply puts \currentstyle in the beginning of the cell, so that if it is \relax, nothing happens, but if there are a \rowstyle command, the row gets styled. notice that a corollary of this is that if you put a \rowstly command in the middle of the row, you affect that column and the following ones. Exercise: what is the effect of {$lc^c$cc}?

Comment: @YossiFarjoun I've edited in an explanation.

Comment: I think `$` isn't a particularly good choice of token, since many editors treat this as beginning a math region and the syntax highlighting is messed up. I'd used `^` and `|`.

Comment: @kynan I'm just using the symbols chosen by the author of the FAQ page linked to in a comment on the question: I didn't pick this particular set of symbols.

Comment: @JosephWright How can I use `\multicolumns{2}{l}{col1 and col2}` in the head column?

Comment: How to apply this only to one table?

Comment: @JosephWright Why do you need `\ignorespaces`?  Does it have anything to do with the spaces before `#1`?

Comment: @macmadness86 The standard LaTeX tabular construct puts an `\ingorespaces` at the start of the cell: it's therefore expected in most peoples input. In the example in the above I don't need a `%` after the `\rowcolor` line due to the space skipping: if it was absent I'd need to worry about the line end.

Comment: @kynan `|` also isn't great as it creates a vertical line. `~` works for me.

Answer (score 18):

This is one of the cases where I find the ConTeXt interface to be much better than LaTeX. To make the first row of a table bold, you just need

```
\setupTABLE[row][1][style=bold]
```

and not change anything in the table body. So, there is a clear separation of style and presentation. Minimal example:

```
\setupTABLE[row][1][style=bold]

\starttext
\startTABLE
  \NC A \NC B \NC C \NC \NR
  \NC A \NC B \NC C \NC \NR
  \NC A \NC B \NC C \NC \NR
\stopTABLE
\stoptext
```

Comment: No-one ever said LaTeX was perfect :-) I keep meaning to have a serious go at tables (for LaTeX3), but have not yet had the time just yet.

Comment: @Joseph: I'm looking forward to your table-package!

Comment: @lockstep: Don't hold your breath - I have the output routine to think about yet :-)

Comment: @JosephWright: I hope you'll call it "carpenter" (as in "table-wright")

Answer (score 15):

For multi-page tables, besides lockstep's solution (from [UK-FAQ](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-wholerow)), you can also use `\rowfont` command in `longtabu` environment from [`tabu`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabu) package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}

Some text.

\vspace{42\baselineskip}

\begin{longtabu}{lcr}
\rowfont{\bfseries}
a & a & a \\
b & b & b \\
c & c & c \\
\end{longtabu}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @lockstep: it's heavily bugged. [See here, for example](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21570/strange-line-spacing-effects-in-longtabu)

Comment: @egreg: There're some bugs in `tabu`, but it is still usable. Another bug I know is that `tabu` cannot used together with `tabularx` and `arydshln`. (It isn't very important since `tabu` provides its own dash line syntax.)

Comment: @Leo: well, just don't use `p` columns or add manually a final `\strut` to each `p` cell.

Comment: @egreg: I agree that the bug pointed out by you is a showstopper.

Comment: Just to let you know that the original question of this answer got merged with this question now.

Answer (score 10):

For tables spanning several pages, simply combine `array` (as in Joseph Wright's answer) and `longtable`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{$}{>{\global\let\currentrowstyle\relax}}
\newcolumntype{^}{>{\currentrowstyle}}
\newcommand{\rowstyle}[1]{\gdef\currentrowstyle{#1}%
  #1\ignorespaces
}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

Some text.

\vspace{42\baselineskip}

\begin{longtable}{$l^c^r}
\rowstyle{\bfseries}
a & a & a \\
b & b & b \\
c & c & c \\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I like this implementation. Do you know of a way to create a new tabular environment that automatically places the $ and ^ before the column declaration?

Answer (score 10):

It is easy with `tabularray` package to set row fonts.  And you can change the environment from `tblr` to `longtblr` to get a long table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{
   width = 0.5\textwidth, colspec = {X[1]X[2]X[3]}, hlines,
   row{1} = {font=\bfseries}, rowhead = 1,
}
   a & b & c \\
   1 & 2 & 3 \\
   1 & 2 & 3 \\
   1 & 2 & 3 \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

In `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, you have a built-in command `\RowStyle` to specify formatting commands to the (end of the) current row. So, it's possible to use `\RowStyle{\bfseries}`. However, the command `\RowStyle` has also a key bold which has the advantage to bold both text mode and math mode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{NiceTabular}{lcr}
\RowStyle[bold]{}
a & a & a \\
b & b & b \\
c & c & c \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]