# Vertical spacing of a table cell

Tags: tables, spacing

I want to tabulate formulas, but I find that the lines of the table cells are too close together, and this is aesthetically unsatisfactory. Example (formulae copied from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates)):

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
Cylindrical & $\displaystyle{{1 \over \rho}{\partial \over \partial\rho}\left(\rho {\partial f \over \partial \rho}\right)
+ {1 \over \rho^2}{\partial^2 f \over \partial \phi^2}  + {\partial^2 f \over \partial z^2}}$\\\hline
Spherical & $\displaystyle{{1 \over r^2}{\partial \over \partial r}\!\left(r^2 {\partial f \over \partial r}\right)
\!+\!{1 \over r^2\!\sin\theta}{\partial \over \partial \theta}\!\left(\sin\theta {\partial f \over \partial \theta}\right)
\!+\!{1 \over r^2\!\sin^2\theta}{\partial^2 f \over \partial \phi^2}}$\\\hline
\end{tabular}
```

gives this

[image: table output]

and you see that the top of the formulas are chopped by the lines. Suggestions?

Comment: See [Column padding in tables](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31672/5764) on ways of adjusting both vertical and horizontal padding of cell entries in `tabular` or `array`.

Comment: @Werner Since this is an answer, you should pose it as such.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

I have solved this in the past by modifying the value of `\arraystretch`

you can do this by adding to your source :

```
{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2} %<- modify value to suit your needs
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
...
\end{tabular}
}
```

Edit:

Actually having researched this a bit more it seems that having equations in the cells has unexpected behaviour, where the space is increase disproportionally at the top (value set  to 3 to start getting the space at the bottom):

[image: tabular with arraystretch set to 3]

more recently I have started to use the `tabu` package to replace all tables (from `tabular` to `tabularx` to `longtable`). It also provide a few more controls. in this case the `\tabulinesep` has a much more appropirate effect on the results:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
   \usepackage{tabu}
   \begin{document}
   {\tabulinesep=1.2mm
   \begin{tabu} {|c|c|}
       \hline
       Cylindrical & $\displaystyle{{1 \over \rho}{\partial \over \partial\rho}\left(\rho {\partial f \over \partial \rho}\right)
       + {1 \over \rho^2}{\partial^2 f \over \partial \phi^2}  + {\partial^2 f \over \partial z^2}}$\\\hline
       Spherical & $\displaystyle{{1 \over r^2}{\partial \over \partial r}\!\left(r^2 {\partial f \over \partial r}\right)
       \!+\!{1 \over r^2\!\sin\theta}{\partial \over \partial \theta}\!\left(\sin\theta {\partial f \over \partial \theta}\right)
       \!+\!{1 \over r^2\!\sin^2\theta}{\partial^2 f \over \partial \phi^2}}$\\\hline
   \end{tabu}}
\end{document}
```

which produces the following result:

[image: tabu with tabulinesep set to 1.2mm]

Comment: Good advice! `tabu` is a really good package!

Comment: `tabu` is no longer actively maintained.

Comment: @LorenzoDonati--Codidact.com correct, and hasn't been for some time. However, this answer is now over 9 years old. There have been other answers since which you can use now based on the newer and maintained `nicematrix` and `tabularray` packages. I was going to add these solutions to my answer, but since they are already there, I didn't see the point.

Comment: Not arguing about that. I just stumbled on your answer after a google search and felt compelled to add that notice. A couple years ago I updated my TeXLive installation and, to my horror, all my heavily-tabu-based documents went awry. I think it's a service for the community to flag that because someone could find the solution interesting but could have an old installation and could invest time learning tabu and then discover the snag when it's too late.

Comment: `{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}...` works with `longtable` for me.

Answer (score 13):

You may use a different table format, leaving out the vertical lines which are by no means necessary; you can also greatly simplify the input with a personal command for partial derivatives:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs,amsmath}

\newcommand{\dpder}[3][]{\dfrac{\partial^{#1}#2}{\partial #3}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lc}
\toprule
Cartesian &
$\dpder[2]{f}{x^2}+\dpder[2]{f}{y^2}+\dpder[2]{f}{z^2}$
\\
\midrule
Cylindrical &
$\dfrac{1}{\rho} \dpder{}{\rho}{\left(\rho \dpder{f}{\rho}\right)}
  + \dfrac{1}{\rho^2} \dpder[2]{f}{\phi^2} + \dpder[2]{f}{z^2}$
\\
\midrule
Spherical &
$\dfrac{1}{r^2}\dpder{}{r}{\left(r^2 \dpder{f}{r}\right)}
  +\dfrac{1}{r^2\sin\theta}\dpder{}{\theta}{\left(\sin\theta \dpder{f}{\theta}\right)}
  +\dfrac{1}{r^2\sin^2\theta}\dpder[2]{f}{\phi^2}$
\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Notice how to avoid unwanted spaces in the "cylindrical" and "spherical" rows by using `{\left(...\right)}` (a couple of braces is sufficient instead of explicit backing up). Note also the usage of `\dfrac` in the definition of `\dpder` that avoids specifying `\displaystyle` (which is however *not* a command taking arguments, but a declaration).

With `booktabs` there's rarely the need to adjust the row spacing.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I usually use macros but in this case I compiled a list of useful formulas for my students, and just copy-pasted it from wikipedia. Can you explain what the second (empty) square braces do in the definition of `\dpder`?

Comment: @yohbs With `\newcommand{\dpder}[3][]{...}` we say that the command has one optional argument and two mandatory ones; the default of the optional argument is empty (the exponent for the `\partial` in the numerator.

Comment: I didn't knew about the spacing`issue. Really nice, egreg! `:)`

Comment: Can `booktabs` be used together with `tabularx` in order to have the `X` column type?

Comment: @Andyc yes, certainly

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative to the outdated `tabu` package, the new [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package provides `rowsep` option for tables:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{|c|c|}
\hline
Cylindrical & $\displaystyle{{1 \over \rho}{\partial \over \partial\rho}\left(\rho {\partial f \over \partial \rho}\right)
+ {1 \over \rho^2}{\partial^2 f \over \partial \phi^2}  + {\partial^2 f \over \partial z^2}}$\\\hline
Spherical & $\displaystyle{{1 \over r^2}{\partial \over \partial r}\!\left(r^2 {\partial f \over \partial r}\right)
\!+\!{1 \over r^2\!\sin\theta}{\partial \over \partial \theta}\!\left(\sin\theta {\partial f \over \partial \theta}\right)
\!+\!{1 \over r^2\!\sin^2\theta}{\partial^2 f \over \partial \phi^2}}$\\\hline
\end{tblr}

\bigskip

\SetTblrInner{rowsep=4pt}

\begin{tblr}{|c|c|}
\hline
Cylindrical & $\displaystyle{{1 \over \rho}{\partial \over \partial\rho}\left(\rho {\partial f \over \partial \rho}\right)
+ {1 \over \rho^2}{\partial^2 f \over \partial \phi^2}  + {\partial^2 f \over \partial z^2}}$\\\hline
Spherical & $\displaystyle{{1 \over r^2}{\partial \over \partial r}\!\left(r^2 {\partial f \over \partial r}\right)
\!+\!{1 \over r^2\!\sin\theta}{\partial \over \partial \theta}\!\left(\sin\theta {\partial f \over \partial \theta}\right)
\!+\!{1 \over r^2\!\sin^2\theta}{\partial^2 f \over \partial \phi^2}}$\\\hline
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I ended up here after googling "*lyx extra space in tables for dfrac*", so this is an answer for LyX, but it probably also applies to plain LaTeX code.

I use the arraystretch-command in my preamble, but if I use `dfrac` in a cell the vertical space will not reflect the needed hight increase.

```
\renewcommand*\arraystretch{1.3}
```

The "tabu" package seems like a good solution, but the package is not recommended by several people because the author didn't tried to maintain backward compability hard enough (as stated by jon [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45479/longtable-in-footnote-leads-to-overfull-page/106427#106427), but I don't know if this is true though). Also I had a hard time getting the "tabu" package to work in LyX.

Anyway,

- **I found a solution** to expand the vertical space in a table cell both upwards and downwards vertically by simply insering an empty box-control before the cell content.

Example code for a single 3-cell row:

```
\hline
Logarithms & $\ln\left(x\right)$ & %
\begin{minipage}[c][10mm][t]{0.1mm}%
%
\end{minipage}$\dfrac{1}{x}$\tabularnewline
```

Resulting PDF without box:
[image]

Resulting PDF with box:
[image: 3cell example PDF output]

I used the following settings in LyX for the box:
[image: Box settings in LyX]

I hope this tip can help someone to expand their vertical cell white spaces in LaTeX!

Answer (score 1):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, you can use `\arraystretch` and `\extrarowheight` of `array` but you have also a key `cell-space-limits`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{NiceTabular}{cc}[hvlines,cell-space-limits=3pt]
Cylindrical & $\displaystyle{{1 \over \rho}{\partial \over \partial\rho}\left(\rho {\partial f \over \partial \rho}\right)
+ {1 \over \rho^2}{\partial^2 f \over \partial \phi^2}  + {\partial^2 f \over \partial z^2}}$\\
Spherical & $\displaystyle{{1 \over r^2}{\partial \over \partial r}\!\left(r^2 {\partial f \over \partial r}\right)
\!+\!{1 \over r^2\!\sin\theta}{\partial \over \partial \theta}\!\left(\sin\theta {\partial f \over \partial \theta}\right)
\!+\!{1 \over r^2\!\sin^2\theta}{\partial^2 f \over \partial \phi^2}}$\\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]