# Equations inside tabular environment, no vertical spacing

Tags: tables, amsmath, booktabs

I have a problem with the spacing of my equations. According to this https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50348/15360 booktabs one should rarely have to regulate the spacing.

But the result of the code below gives me:

[image: Table with equations]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb!]
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
  \caption{Parameters which Torque logs.}
  \label{tbl:2_1_1}
  \begin{tabular}{c|c|c} 
                                                                \toprule
  {$\mathbf{q_1/q_2}$} & {$\mathbf{0}$} & {$\mathbf{1}$}       \\ \midrule
  \multirow{2}{*}{$\mathbf{0}$}                                & 
    $\displaystyle\frac{\mathrm{d}v_C}{\mathrm{d}t} = 
-\frac{1}{C}I_\mathrm{load}$                                  &
    $\displaystyle\frac{\mathrm{d}v_C}{\mathrm{d}t} = 
\frac{1}{C}i_L - \frac{1}{C}I_\mathrm{load}$                  \\
                                                             &
    $\displaystyle\frac{\mathrm{d}i_L}{\mathrm{d}t} = 
-\frac{R_L}{L}i_L$                                            &     
    $\displaystyle\frac{\mathrm{d}i_L}{\mathrm{d}t} = 
-\frac{1}{L}v_C - \frac{R_L}{L}i_L$                       \\ \hline
  \multirow{2}{*}{$\mathbf{1}$}                            &
    $\displaystyle\frac{\mathrm{d}v_C}{\mathrm{d}t} = 
-\frac{R_L}{L}i_L - \frac{1}{L}V_s$                       &
    $\displaystyle\frac{\mathrm{d}v_C}{\mathrm{d}t} = 
\frac{1}{C}i_L - \frac{1}{C}I_\mathrm{load}$                  \\
                                                             &
    $\displaystyle\frac{\mathrm{d}i_L}{\mathrm{d}t} = 
-\frac{1}{C}I_\mathrm{load}$                                  &
    $\displaystyle\frac{\mathrm{d}i_L}{\mathrm{d}t} = 
-\frac{1}{L}v_L - \frac{R_L}{L}i_L + \frac{1}{L}V_s$          \\ \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I also used `$\begin{aligned} ... \end{aligned}$` for combining the equations such that you don't have to use the `\multirow` command.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb!]
  \caption{Parameters which Torque logs.}
  \label{tbl:2_1_1}
  \begin{tabular}{c|c|c} 
                                                               \toprule
  {$\mathbf{q_1/q_2}$} & {$\mathbf{0}$} & {$\mathbf{1}$}            \\ \midrule
  {$\mathbf{0}$} & 
$\begin{aligned}
\frac{\mathrm{d}v_C}{\mathrm{d}t} &= -\frac{1}{C}I_\mathrm{load}
\\
\frac{\mathrm{d}i_L}{\mathrm{d}t} &= -\frac{R_L}{L}i_L
\\
\end{aligned}$ 
                &
$\begin{aligned}
\frac{\mathrm{d}v_C}{\mathrm{d}t} &= \frac{1}{C}i_L - \frac{1}{C}I_\mathrm{load}
\\
\frac{\mathrm{d}i_L}{\mathrm{d}t} &= -\frac{1}{L}v_C - \frac{R_L}{L}i_L
\\
\end{aligned}$                                  \\ \hline 
  {$\mathbf{1}$} &  
$\begin{aligned}
\frac{\mathrm{d}v_C}{\mathrm{d}t} &= -\frac{R_L}{L}i_L - \frac{1}{L}V_s
\\
\frac{\mathrm{d}i_L}{\mathrm{d}t} &= -\frac{1}{C}I_\mathrm{load}
\\
\end{aligned}$
                &
$\begin{aligned}
\frac{\mathrm{d}v_C}{\mathrm{d}t} &= \frac{1}{C}i_L - \frac{1}{C}I_\mathrm{load}
\\
\frac{\mathrm{d}i_L}{\mathrm{d}t} &= -\frac{1}{L}v_L - \frac{R_L}{L}i_L +
\frac{1}{L}V_s 
\\
\end{aligned}$                                  \\ \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Playing with `arraystretch` or `\\[8mm]` didn't help either.

Comment: I suggest dropping the use of vertical rules, as purported in the [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/booktabs.pdf). See also [How to add extra spaces between rows in tabular environment?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26690/5764) Why didn't playing [around] with `\arraystretch` or `\\[<len>]` help?

Comment: @Werner \arraystretch did work at some value but the header then got far to big, e.g. to much vertical spacing. But I fixed it now... I don't know why \\[<len>] didn't help but `\addlinespace` did.

Comment: @Werner: I think you mean "proposed" or "propounded", not "purported", which doesn't make sense here. :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a possibility; I omitted the vertical rules: there's (almost) never need for them.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{position=top}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb!]
\centering
\caption{Parameters which Torque logs.}
\label{tbl:2_1_1}
$\begin{array}{cll}
\toprule
\mathbf{q}_1/\mathbf{q}_2 & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\mathbf{0}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\mathbf{1}} \\
\midrule
\addlinespace
\mathbf{0} & 
  \begin{aligned}
    \frac{\mathrm{d}v_C}{\mathrm{d}t} &= -\frac{1}{C}I_\mathrm{load} \\[1ex]
    \frac{\mathrm{d}i_L}{\mathrm{d}t} &= -\frac{R_L}{L}i_L
  \end{aligned} &
  \begin{aligned}
    \frac{\mathrm{d}v_C}{\mathrm{d}t} &= \frac{1}{C}i_L - \frac{1}{C}I_\mathrm{load} \\[1ex]
    \frac{\mathrm{d}i_L}{\mathrm{d}t} &= -\frac{1}{L}v_C - \frac{R_L}{L}i_L
  \end{aligned} \\
\addlinespace
\midrule
\addlinespace
\mathbf{1} &
  \begin{aligned}
    \frac{\mathrm{d}v_C}{\mathrm{d}t} &= -\frac{R_L}{L}i_L - \frac{1}{L}V_s \\[1ex]
    \frac{\mathrm{d}i_L}{\mathrm{d}t} &= -\frac{1}{C}I_\mathrm{load}
  \end{aligned} &
  \begin{aligned}
    \frac{\mathrm{d}v_C}{\mathrm{d}t} &= \frac{1}{C}i_L - \frac{1}{C}I_\mathrm{load} \\[1ex]
    \frac{\mathrm{d}i_L}{\mathrm{d}t} &= -\frac{1}{L}v_L - \frac{R_L}{L}i_L + \frac{1}{L}V_s 
  \end{aligned} \\
\addlinespace
\bottomrule
\end{array}$
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Note the `\addlinespace` for leaving a bit more room and the `[1ex]` spacing between the rows in `aligned` (it's common to use a spacing when fractions are involved. Left alignment seems preferable.

[image]

Comment: @WG- I changed a bit my answer; the `\mathstrut` trick is really not necessary and `\addlinespace` is preferable.

Comment: Okay! Thanks for your answer. As you can see in the comment to my own question I figured out also that `\addlinespace` could do the trick to add more space. Using the array environment seems also a bit smoother then the tabular environment.