# Balanced vertical padding in table & Why does \vphantom has width?

Tags: tables, spacing

I think I have a simpler & better solution to these questions on [how to add vertical padding to tabular cells](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50332/vertical-spacing-of-a-table-cell) [so they looks less crammed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31672/column-and-row-padding-in-tables). However, my solution which make use of `\vphantom` somehow produces unwanted horizontal space. So, I am asking for how to remove the horizontal space.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\newcommand{\balancedVPhantom}[1]{ % gives minimum vertical size
    \vphantom{$\vcenter{\hbox{\rule{0pt}{#1}}}$}
}
\newcommand{\newrow}{\balancedVPhantom{2em}\\ \hline}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
    \hline
    This row has normal space. \\ \hline
    This row has balanced increased space.\newrow
    \balancedVPhantom{2em}But why does vphantom has width? \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of the solution to balanced vertical padding in table]

As you can see, the last row is shifted to the right even though I use `\vphantom`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of errors in your macro; the most obvious is that a `%` is missing at the end of the line and there is moreover a space after the opening brace, the second is in the fact that `\vphantom` doesn't start horizontal mode, so if you use it at the beginning of a paragraph the result will not be what's expected, because you'd get an empty line.

I propose a simpler macro:

```
\documentclass[border=4]{standalone}

\newcommand{\balancedVPhantom}[1]{% gives minimum vertical size
  $\mathsurround=0pt \vcenter{\hrule width0pt height #1}$\ignorespaces
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
This row has normal space. \\
\hline
\balancedVPhantom{2em} This row has balanced increased space. \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

With `\ignorespaces` it doesn't matter if you have a space after the argument. The setting of `\mathsurround=0pt` is needed when math mode is used for any purpose not directly involved into producing a math formula. (Although forgetting it is usually not important, because the parameter is rarely set to a nonzero value.)

[image]

Comment: Great improvement and explanation. `\mathsurround=0pt` really is what I wanted to use instead of `\vphantom` but I did't know the command.

Comment: @Billiska The missing `\mathsurround` wasn't your problem, unless you set the parameter to a nonzero value (or the class you're using does).

Comment: Ah, yes. Just tested it. I mistakenly attributed the space problem to math mode.

Answer (score 3):

Because it adds a space. The `%` at the end of the third line corrects this.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\newcommand{\balancedVPhantom}[1]{% gives minimum vertical size
\vphantom{$\vcenter{\hbox{\rule{0pt}{#1}}}$}%
}
\newcommand{\newrow}{\balancedVPhantom{2em}\\\hline}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|l|}
    \hline
    This row has normal space. \\ \hline
    This row has balanced increased space.\newrow
  \balancedVPhantom{2em}But why does vphantom has width? \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I noticed that you also remove the space between `{` and `%` on the second line, and the space in front of the third line. Even though I tested that these don't have any effect, I don't understand why they don't. Shouldn't they also add space in front of the `\vphantom`?

Comment: Only as a general rule that additional spaces MAY cause problems.

Comment: There goes beautiful indentation... I'm sad.

Comment: There is no need to remove the spaces at the *beginning* of a line, which are ignored by TeX (unless in very special situations when `\obeylines` is in force, which is of course not the case).

Comment: @Billiska the space before your `%` on the first line does add a space token and would add a space to the output if the phantom was used mid-line, it didn't as used because a space token in vertical mode is ignored, it does not start a paragraph. The indentation spaces at the next line do not form a space token at all.