# Is it possible to use tabularx inside a longtable environment?

Tags: longtable, tabularx

Is it possible to use `tabularx` inside a `longtable` environment?

If not, is there any way I can get the "X" funcionality of `tabularx` with the option of long tables ---In order for me to be able to break them in two pages?  Using `longtabu` is not an option, as stated by @jon [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/106427/27833):

> I would recommend staying away from `tabu` as the package author is
>   still fiddling with things and explicitly promised that there would
>   not be backwards compatibility. See [here](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/browse_thread/thread/c511894c2ef8b822/df91b50e43a35c86?lnk=gst&q=tabu#df91b50e43a35c86) for the discussion.

UPDATE:

Using the package `ltxtable` suggested by @Alan Munn (Writeen by @David Carlisle) I have the current Minimal Non-Working Example

Main File:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{ltxtable}

\begin{document}
Hello.

\LTXtable{\textwidth}{VersionOne}

\end{document}
```

Where the file *VersionOne* goes:

```
\begin{longtable}{XX}
\caption{A very long table}\\
WHO                 & \hspace{5mm} World Health Organization\\[1mm]
GDP                 & \hspace{5mm} Gross Domestic Product\\[1mm]
PPP                 & \hspace{5mm} Purchasing Power Parities\\[1mm]
\label{tab:LongtableOne}
\end{longtable}
```

When I try to run this code, I get a Emergency Stop and a fatal error.  Am I writing this correctly?

Comment: There is the `ltxtable` package by David Carlisle which combines the capabilities of both.

Comment: @AlanMunn, Could you please give an example?  The documentation (ftp://ftp.di.uminho.pt/pub/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/carlisle/ltxtable.pdf) is not very explicative, and I wasn't able to run anything

Comment: Just put your longtable in a separate file and include it with `\LTXtable{\textwidth}{name-of-file-with-table}`

Comment: And what about the Xs?  Should I also write a `tabularx` environment?

Comment: @MarioS.E. No just use X in the longtable preamble

Comment: It continues to give me an error. I'm going to write a MWE in the question

Comment: After `caption` you need a line break. `\caption{A very long table}\\ ` This is the special behaviour of `longtable`

Comment: Fixed it, and although I don't get any errors, now I can't see the table

Answer (score 13):

As stated in the comments for `ltxtable` the `longtable` has to be in a separate file. Processing the updated example (twice) with `pdflatex` produces

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The new LaTeX3 package [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) is an alternative to the outdated `tabu` package. You can use `X` columns in `longtblr` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}[
  caption = {A very long table},
  label = {tab:LongtableOne},
]{X[1]X[2]}
\toprule
  WHO & World Health Organization \\
  GDP & Gross Domestic Product    \\
  PPP & Purchasing Power Parities \\
\bottomrule
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]