# Vertically align individual cells in a table

Tags: longtable, tabu

I am wanting the ability to vertically align any cell within a table. This appears possible but only on a per column or row basis. At the moment I can horizontally align the contents of individual cells with the help of the `\raggedleft` and `\centering` commands. However, `\multicolumn` applies vertical alignment for the whole row and the `longtabu` environment can only specify the alignment type per column.

The following is an example of the table I want to create where both horizontal and vertical alignments need to be set for each cell instead of per row or column:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}      
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multirow}

\newcolumntype{M}{m{\dimexpr 1\tabucolX+1\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax}}
\newcolumntype{P}{p{\dimexpr 1\tabucolX+1\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax}}
\newcolumntype{B}{b{\dimexpr 1\tabucolX+1\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax}}

\newcolumntype{H}{>{\begin{minipage}[b]{\hsize}}B<{\end{minipage}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtabu} to 150mm [l] {|X[l]|X[l]|X[l]|}
\hline 
\multicolumn{1}{|P|}{ \lipsum[1]} & \multicolumn{1}{H|}{\centering H: Center, V:Center} & \multicolumn{1}{B|}{\raggedleft \multirow{1}{*}[-2\baselineskip]{H:Right, V:Bottom}} \tabularnewline
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|P|}{\lipsum[1]} & \multicolumn{1}{P|}{H: Left, V:Top} & \multicolumn{1}{M|}{\centering H:Center, V:Center} \tabularnewline
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|P|}{\lipsum[1]} & \multicolumn{1}{M|}{\raggedleft H: Right, V:Center} & \multicolumn{1}{B|}{H:Left, V:Bottom} \tabularnewline
\hline 
\tabuphantomline 
\end{longtabu}

\end{document}
```

**Update:**

Attempting the solutions presented in "[Move tabular entry to bottom of row](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/166808/43952)" won't work.

The first solution I believe simply adjusts the entire column by creating a new column type:

```
\newcolumntype{B}{>{\begin{minipage}[b]{\hsize}}X<{\end{minipage}}}
```

This doesn't help my problem where I need the vertical alignment applied to individual cells, not a whole column. Applying this column type to `\multicolumn` doesn't appear to work.

The second solution places a `\baselineskip` into the optional parameter of `\multirow` which works initially but seems to become vertically centred as soon as the cell becomes a certain height.

I have updated my example above to show how it breaks.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry when I say "vertically align" I am not referring to the state of being vertically centred in the middle but the ability to be positioned vertically e.g. Top, Middle or Bottom.

Comment: You can use `m` or `b` columns from `array` package.

Comment: As I mention in my question I am looking to apply vertical positioning at the cell level instead of per column. For `\multicolumn` only one column-spec is allowed.

Comment: My recommendation: stay away from `longtabu`.  The developer has already said that he is going to make some major changes and it is not going to be backward compatible.  You can find more about this in this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106452/is-it-possible-to-use-tabularx-inside-a-longtable-environment

Comment: David Carlisle's answer at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166808/move-tabular-entry-to-bottom-of-row can address this problem.

Comment: Have updated my question to show how David Carlisle's answer doesn't appear to be working for me.

Answer (score 2):

> David Carlisle's answer doesn't appear to be working for me.

hmph:-)

Works for me:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}  
\usepackage{array}    

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter


\newcolumntype{P}{p{.3\textwidth}}


\newcommand\m[1]{\multicolumn{1}{#1}}

\newcommand\zc[2]{%
\setbox0\hbox{\parbox[c]{.3\textwidth}{#2}}%
\smash{\raisebox{\dimexpr(\csname PDFSAVEe#1\endcsname sp-
                         \csname PDFSAVEb#1\endcsname sp)/2\relax}{\box0}}}
\newcommand\zb[2]{%
\setbox0\hbox{\parbox[t]{.3\textwidth}{#2}}%
\smash{\raisebox{\dimexpr\csname PDFSAVEe#1\endcsname sp-
                         \csname PDFSAVEb#1\endcsname sp\relax}{\box0}}}

\def\foo#1{\leavevmode
\expandafter\ifx\csname PDFSAVE#1\endcsname\relax
\expandafter\gdef\csname PDFSAVE#1\endcsname{0}%
\fi
\pdfsavepos\write\@auxout{\gdef\string\PDFSAVE#1{\the\pdflastypos}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|P|P|P|}
\hline 
\foo{ba}\lipsum*[1]\foo{ea} &
\zc{a}{\centering H: Center, V:Center} &
\zb{a}{\raggedleft H:Right, V:Bottom} \tabularnewline
\hline
\foo{bb}\lipsum*[1]\foo{eb} & 
{H: Left, V:Top} &
\zc{b}{\centering H:Center, V:Center} \tabularnewline
\hline
\foo{bc}\lipsum*[1]\foo{ec} &
\zc{c}{\raggedleft H: Right, V:Center} & 
\zb{c}{H:Left, V:Bottom} \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That quote... `:)`