# Move tabular entry to bottom of row

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, tabularx

How do I get the last column text to be at the bottom of the row?

[image]

That is I want the `XXX` to be aligned with the line containing the arrow.

I tried playing around with `\multirow{3}{-3ex}{XXX}`, but obviously I don't understand `\multirow`.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}[t]{l X p{1.3cm}}
        & Header & Title \\\cmidrule(lr){2-2}\cmidrule(lr){3-3}
        a. & Some text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
            text text text text text text text text text text 
            Want XXX on this line $\rightarrow$%
         & XXX\\
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/113026/32888) helpful?

Comment: @Adam: Yep, very useful, but surprisingly different answers than here.

Comment: Oh I just saw the link Adam gave is same as answer I just posted. Probably close this as dup?

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate. OP wants two different vertical alignments in same row.

Comment: @Ignasi OK new answer posted:-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Edited answer, using different mechanism)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\makeatletter
\def\foo#1{\leavevmode
\expandafter\ifx\csname PDFSAVE#1\endcsname\relax
\expandafter\gdef\csname PDFSAVE#1\endcsname{0sp}%
\fi
\pdfsavepos\write\@auxout{\gdef\string\PDFSAVE#1{\the\pdflastypos}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
    \noindent
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}[t]{l X p{1.3cm}}
        & Header & Title \\\cmidrule(lr){2-2}\cmidrule(lr){3-3}
        a. & \foo{a}Some text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
            text text text text text text text text text text 
            Want XXX on this line $\rightarrow$\foo{b}%
         & \smash{\raisebox{\dimexpr\PDFSAVEb sp-\PDFSAVEa sp\relax}{XXX}}\\
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

---

The original answer moved the baseline of the X column to the bottom using

```
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{b{#1}}
```

But that affects all `X` columns, and also makes the `a.` align on the bottom row.
The latter problem could be fixed by moving the `a.` into the second column (with a hanging indent)

If you only want to change the alignment of some X columns in a table, then you can use:

```
>{\begin{minipage}[b]{\hsize}}X<{\end{minipage}} :-)
```

Comment: But this solution also aligns first column `a` to the bottom.

Comment: Yes or rather it doesn't move the 1st and 3rd columns down all, it moves the 2nd column up. (the a. could be moved to the start of the paragraph in the X column, where it belongs:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: But what if it was _not_ part of the 2nd column? I don't really like your `\parbox` solution at the other answer. Can't you have two different `X` column types in the same table: One `b{#1}` and another `t{#1}`?

Comment: You can if you want, yes (or simpler just use minipipage withing the column spec so) >{\begin{minipage}{\hsize}[b]}X<{\end{minipage}} is a one-off b-alignment in an otherwise p (top) aligned table

Comment: The `minipage` idea works better with `>{\begin{minipage}[b]{\hsize}}X<{\end{minipage}}` :-) But it is kind of weird to apply something to column 2, to get the desired positioning in column 3 -- same reason I dislike the `\parbox` solution in [Vertical alignment in tabular cells with variable height](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113022/vertical-alignment-in-tabular-cells-with-variable-height).

Comment: @PeterGrill If the tex solution doesn't fit with your mental model you need to change the latter not the former:-) Every table row has a single baseline running through it and the question is where do you want each cell relative to that baseline. If you say XXX is on the baseline that's the default so you need the bottom row of the X column to be on teh baseline which is a b column. Or yo say teh baseline goes through the top row of the X column (as in my revised answer) then you need to move XXX off that baseline.

Comment: :-) Yes, I WILL submit to the TeX model of thinking. :-)  I think I will go with the `minipage` solution, so please post a bit of code in the answer as well.

Comment: I@PeterGrill f I post the minipage version, where would you like the `[b]` argument:-)

Comment: @PeterGrill answer updated again

Comment: FYI, I am accepting this answer as the `minipage` solution defers the codding to the `tabular` specification and does not need tweaking on a per cell basis. Some of my lines are not the full length of the column and they align the way I want with this solution.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to play with `\multirow`, you can use the second optional argument, which is the "fixup", a length for fine tuning the position.

In your case it should be `-2\baselineskip`

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
    \noindent
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}[t]{l X p{1.3cm}}
        & Header & Title \\\cmidrule(lr){2-2}\cmidrule(lr){3-3}
        a. & Some text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
            text text text text text text text text text text
            Want XXX on this line $\rightarrow$%
         & \multirow{1}{*}[-2\baselineskip]{XXX}\\
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Depending on the type of content associated with `XXX`, the following is an easy way of obtain the bottom-alignment that doesn't require knowledge of the preceding column entries:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}[t]{l X p{1.3cm}}
  & Header & Title \\\cmidrule(lr){2-2}\cmidrule(lr){3-3}
  a. & Some text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
      text text text text text text text text text text 
      Want XXX on this line $\rightarrow$
   & \\[-\normalbaselineskip] && XXX
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Idea: Set `XXX` on its own line, but overlaid with the bottom of the previous line using `\\[-\normalbaselineskip]`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `{NiceTabularX}` of `nicematrix` and its built-in command `\Block`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{NiceTabularX}{\linewidth}[t]{l X p{1.3cm}}
    & Header & Title \\\cmidrule(lr){2-2}\cmidrule(lr){3-3}
    a. & Some text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
        text text text text text text text text text text 
        Want XXX on this line $\rightarrow$%
     & \Block[B]{}{XXX \strut} 
\end{NiceTabularX}
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/TikZ nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Works great after 3rd run.