# different vertical alignment of text for different columns in tabularx environment

Tags: tabularx, alignment, vertical

I asked a question before, howerver it was marked as a duplicate and closed down. Unfortunately the provided solution did not answer the problem, so I am reposting it.

I am using tabularx environment and in the MWE I have three columns. The first column contains short text, the second column contains long text and the third column contains short text again.

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{6cm}{|p{2cm}|b{2cm}|p{2cm}|} 
short 1 & long text spanning more than one row & short 2 \\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

As expected, the result is that both `short 1` and `short 2` align to the bottom.

[image]

If I change the setting on middle column from `b{2cm}` to `p{cm}`, as expected both `short 1` and `short` 2 align to the top.

I would like to make `short 1` align to the top and `short 2` align to the bottom. How can I achieve that?

Thanks in advance.

SUGGESTED SOLUTION THAT DOES NOT WORK:

Following a suggestion by @NBur who pointed me to [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/395356/different-vertical-alignment-of-text-in-4-column-table-tabularx), I've implemented the following changes:

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcolumntype{C}{b{2cm}<{\vfill}}

\begin{document}


\begin{tabularx}{6cm}{|C|b{2cm}|p{2cm}|} 
short 1 & long text spanning more than one row & short 2 \\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately this code brings up the text only by one line and not all the way up to the top of the cell, so it does not work.

[image]

Are there any other suggestions?

Comment: [Problem with Table Vertical Alignment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6355/134144)   and [Move tabular entry to bottom of row](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/166808/134144) are also related.

Comment: @leandriis Thank you for your reply! That works, I appreciate you pointing me out in the right direction. It's surprising that achieving something that looks quite basic requires such a seemingling "hackish" approach!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution with `tblr` environment of [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package, using `head` and `foot` alignmnet types:

```
\documentclass{article}    

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{|h{2cm}|m{2cm}|f{2cm}|} 
short 1 & long text spanning more than one row & short 2 \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]