# What's the proper way to center tabu?

Tags: tabu

I'm trying to create a longtabu that is a bit wider than the normal margins.

other answers refer to adjustwidth and tabular/tabularx/table. They don't appear to work for longtabu/tabu.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{changepage}

\begin{document}

\newlength{\mylength}
\setlength{\mylength}{\paperwidth}
\addtolength{\mylength}{-2cm}

%\hspace*{-4.5cm}\begin{minipage}[c]{\mylength}
\begin{adjustwidth}{-20cm}{}
\begin{longtabu} to \mylength  {| p{1.5cm} | p{2cm} | p{5cm}| X |}
\hline
a & b & c & d \\
\hline
\end{longtabu}

\end{adjustwidth}
%\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

EDITS:
Using minipage breaks the long table aspect of the table. Just runs off the end of the page if you have a lot of rows.

The commented hspace/minipage does work but it looks clunky. Surely, there's a perttier way. Why can't I just say "center this table on the page. forget the margins"?

no I don't want to move over by 20cm. it's a number I picked to make it clear that something actually happened.

The data in this example is only an example. My actual data wants to use as much of the page as possible. Use of the right side is a simple matter of overflow. I also want to get back some of the space on the left.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! Well, it is not on ***a*** page, is it. It is (potentially) on several pages and that makes it more complicated...

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! You can't seriously want to reduce the left margin by 20cm, surely? I'm actually finding it hard to figure out what the problem is you are trying to solve. I tried to wind back your adjustments to just get the table before you tried to box it and so on, but then the table isn't too wide. I just get an underfull vertical box. Can you change your example so it reproduces the problem?

Comment: My recommendation: run away from `tabu`

Comment: @cfr i think we need some thing like \LTright and \LTleft for longtable but i don't know.

Comment: @cfr see updates to the question.

Comment: @MarioS.E. - why not tabu? http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables seems to clearly favor it.

Comment: We still can't use your code to reproduce the problem because you've not put enough in the table to make it too wide.

Comment: @mmccoo [Here's why not](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/121847/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to avoid tabu. As stated by jon [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45479/longtable-in-footnote-leads-to-overfull-page/106427#106427):

> I would recommend staying away from tabu as the package author is
>   still fiddling with things and explicitly promised that there would
>   not be backwards compatibility. See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45479/longtable-in-footnote-leads-to-overfull-page/106427#106427) for the discussion.

If you are trying to get the 'X' funcionality of tabularx with the breakable option of longtable, Alan Munn recommends using the ltxtable package ([link to CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/carlisle/)), written by David Carlisle (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106452/is-it-possible-to-use-tabularx-inside-a-longtable-environment)).

Other thing you can do is still use tabularx, put it inside a table environment and reduce its size. You can always rotate it 90 degrees to get a more space.

For more information about table packages, please refer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12672/which-tabular-packages-do-which-tasks-and-which-packages-conflict/12673#12673).

Comment: this does not answer the question (sorry)

Comment: @touhami Too long for a comment, wasn't intended as a comprehensive answer.

Comment: I switched to using longtable.