# Strange line spacing effects in longtabu

Tags: tables, line-spacing, longtable, tabu

I got some strange effect with `longtabu`:
[image]
As you can see the line with **λ** seems to be closer to the above line than to the one below of it. I cant’t figure out why …

This is the code with which I produced the above picture:

```
\documentclass[
    fontsize=11pt,
]{scrbook}

\usepackage{xltxtra}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage[osf]{libertine}

\begin{document}
    \begin{longtabu} to \textwidth {lX}
         \textbf{L} & Musica incantans sive poema exprimens musicae vires per illam juvene in insaniam
        acto et musici inde periculum. Authore Roberto South Art. Bac. ex Aede Christi. Oxonii, Typis
        Leon. Lichfield Academiae Typographi, Impensis Tho. Robinson. Anno 1655. \\ 
         \textbf{λ} & \textit{Überarbeitete, zweite Fassung des Gedichts zwischen 1655 und 1667.} \\ 
         \textbf{W} & Musica incantans sive poema exprimens musicae vires juvenem in insaniam adigentis et
        musici inde periculum. Authore Roberto South Art. Bac. ex Aede Christi. Oxonii, Typis W.\,H.,
        Impensis G. West. Anno Dom. 1667. \\ 
    \end{longtabu}%
\end{document}
```

The workaround is to put an invisible rule to the **λ** line to make it higher.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It seems that **tabu** forgets to put a `\strut` at the end of an `X` cell, so

```
\begin{longtabu} to \textwidth {lX<{\strut}}
```

should solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you! I tried to put a `\strut` manually before the `λ`. But that didn’t work. Do you know why? [Shall I send this as a bug report to the `tabu` developer?]

Comment: I've sent a message to `comp.text.tex` to signal the problem; tabu's author is very active there.

Comment: Ah, and the problem with the strut before the `λ` is that it adjusts the row's height, but what's wrong is the depth of the *previous* row.

Comment: The key is that the one line `X` column correctly sets the following row.

Comment: This problem still exists.
It affects all cells in an `X` column that have more than one line (both by manual and automatic line breaks). One-liners are not affected. And – just to add because I grew a grey hair or two over this before noticing – every `X` column that may have more than 1 line needs the explicit `\strut` in the declaration.

Comment: @dariok I don't know what to say: the workaround, as you seem to be telling, works.

Comment: @egreg Yes, the workaround does indeed work. Yet this is a 9 year old problem that’s still confusing people from time to time and forgetting to add the strut to all X columns might be a common cause for irritation. Hence, I thought a comment that reflects this state and contains a reminder for potential problems might just be helpful for other users hitting this thread.

Comment: @dariok The answer is: don’t use `tabu`. It’s buggy and unmaintained.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is to to put

```
\tabulinesep=1.2mm
```

before the `longtabu`-environment.

```
\documentclass[
    fontsize=11pt,
]{scrbook}

\usepackage{xltxtra}

\usepackage{array, tabu, longtable}

\usepackage[osf]{libertine}

\begin{document}
\tabulinesep=1.3mm
    \begin{longtabu} to \textwidth {lX}
         \textbf{L} & Musica incantans sive poema exprimens musicae vires per illam juvene in insaniam
        acto et musici inde periculum. Authore Roberto South Art. Bac. ex Aede Christi. Oxonii, Typis
        Leon. Lichfield Academiae Typographi, Impensis Tho. Robinson. Anno 1655. \\ 
         \textbf{λ} & \textit{Überarbeitete, zweite Fassung des Gedichts zwischen 1655 und 1667.} \\ 
         \textbf{W} & Musica incantans sive poema exprimens musicae vires juvenem in insaniam adigentis et
        musici inde periculum. Authore Roberto South Art. Bac. ex Aede Christi. Oxonii, Typis W.\,H.,
        Impensis G. West. Anno Dom. 1667. \\ 
    \end{longtabu}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The new LaTeX3 package [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) is an alternative to the outdated `tabu` package. You may try the `longtblr` environment:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt,]{scrbook}

\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage[osf]{libertine}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\SetTblrInner[longtblr]{rowsep=0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}[
  caption = {Long Caption},
]{colspec={lX},width=\linewidth,column{1}={font=\bfseries}}
  L & Musica incantans sive poema exprimens musicae vires per illam juvene in insaniam
    acto et musici inde periculum. Authore Roberto South Art. Bac. ex Aede Christi. Oxonii, Typis
    Leon. Lichfield Academiae Typographi, Impensis Tho. Robinson. Anno 1655. \\ 
  λ & \textit{Überarbeitete, zweite Fassung des Gedichts zwischen 1655 und 1667.} \\ 
  W & Musica incantans sive poema exprimens musicae vires juvenem in insaniam adigentis et
    musici inde periculum. Authore Roberto South Art. Bac. ex Aede Christi. Oxonii, Typis W.\,H.,
    Impensis G. West. Anno Dom. 1667. \\ 
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]