# Fixed table width with even alignment

Tags: tables, spacing

I like to use a table layout where the width of the table is fixed to 7cm. I can do this using:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{array,tabularx}
\newcolumntype{+}{>{\global\let\currentrowstyle\relax}}
\newcolumntype{^}{>{\currentrowstyle}}
\newcommand{\rowstyle}[1]{\gdef\currentrowstyle{#1}%
  #1\ignorespaces}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\@floatboxreset{\centering\sffamily\small}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{table}

\begin{tabular*}{7cm}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}|>{\bfseries}+l|^c|^c|}
\hline\rowstyle{\bfseries}%
            & property  & number    \\ \hline
Something   & yes       & 1554      \\
Item        & no        & 2         \\ \hline
\end{tabular*}\\
\vspace{.5cm}

\newcolumntype{;}{l@{}}% dummy column
\begin{tabular*}{7cm}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}|;>{\bfseries}+l;|^c;|^c;|}
\hline\rowstyle{\bfseries}%
&            && property  && number  &  \\ \hline
&Something   && yes       && 1554    &  \\
&Item        && no        && 2       &  \\ \hline
\end{tabular*}\\
\vspace{.5cm}

\newcolumntype{;}{X@{}}% dummy column
\begin{tabularx}{7cm}{|+;>{\bfseries}l;|;^c;|;^c;|}
\hline\rowstyle{\bfseries}%
&            &&& property  &&& number   & \\ \hline
&Something   &&& yes       &&& 1554     & \\
&Item        &&& no        &&& 2        & \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}\\
\vspace{.5cm}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{.52cm}
\begin{tabular}{|>{\bfseries}+l|^c|^c|}
\hline\rowstyle{\bfseries}%
            & property  & number    \\ \hline
Something   & yes       & 1554      \\
Item        & no        & 2         \\ \hline
\end{tabular}


\end{table}

\end{document}
```

In the code, the first table doesn't align nicely. The second and third table require the use complex code for formatting the table in the document. Where I'd rather separate the formatting from the contents. The fourth example works nicely, but requires manual tuning of tabcolsep.

How should I define a tabular environment that dynamically increases the cell margins to obtain the desired table width?

Comment: Use the `tabularx` package, see `texdoc tabularx`.

Comment: @Christoph: Then you would have to know the width of column without space to calculate the right factors for the `X` columns to get evenly distributed space across columns.

Comment: You could look at `tabularx` or `tabulary` packages, but the space added by `\extracolsep` is evenly distributed if you add a final `@{}` after the `|` to match the `@{}` at the start. (or use `!` instead of `@` so it does not remove the `\tabcolsep` at that point.

Comment: It _always_ helps if you post a small complete example document that shows the problem.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I could not get your suggestions to work. The '!' version does compile, but the only change is small lines sticking out at the left. Adding '@{}' also does not improve the situation. I did add a full example document now.

Answer (score 4):

Usually LaTeX does not use TeX's `\tabskip` to set the space between the columns, but it uses the dimen register `\tabcolsep`. The latter is also inserted between a column and the vertical line opposite to `\tabskip` that is only inserted between columns. `\extracolsep` sets `\tabcolsep`. The example in the question contains a table with three columns, six `\tabcolsep` and two `\tabskip`.

Therefore a workaround is the use of dummy columns:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{;}{l@{}}% dummy column

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}|;l;|c;|c;|}
\hline
&     && 1   && 2  &\\ \hline
& a   && x   && 15 &\\
& b   && y   && 2  &\\ \hline
\end{tabular*}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result tabular*]

Variant with `\rowstyle`:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{;}{l@{}}% dummy column

\newcolumntype{+}{>{\global\let\currentrowstyle\relax}}
\newcolumntype{^}{>{\currentrowstyle}}
\newcommand*{\rowstyle}[1]{%
  \gdef\currentrowstyle{#1}%
  #1\ignorespaces
}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}|+;>{\bfseries}l;|^c;|^c;|}
\hline
\rowstyle{\bfseries}%
&     && 1   && 2  &\\ \hline
& a   && x   && 15 &\\
& b   && y   && 2  &\\ \hline
\end{tabular*}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result tabular* with \rowstyle]

Another workaround is `tabularx` with dummy `X` columns. These columns are the place where the evenly distributed space should go:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{;}{X@{}}% dummy column

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|;l;|;c;|;c;|}
\hline
&     &&& 1   &&& 2  &\\ \hline
& a   &&& x   &&& 15 &\\
& b   &&& y   &&& 2  &\\ \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result tabularx]

Variant with `\rowstyle`:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{;}{X@{}}% dummy column

\newcolumntype{+}{>{\global\let\currentrowstyle\relax}}
\newcolumntype{^}{>{\currentrowstyle}}
\newcommand*{\rowstyle}[1]{%
  \gdef\currentrowstyle{#1}%
  #1\ignorespaces
}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|+;>{\bfseries}l;|;^c;|;^c;|}
\hline
\rowstyle{\bfseries}%
&     &&& 1   &&& 2  &\\ \hline
& a   &&& x   &&& 15 &\\
& b   &&& y   &&& 2  &\\ \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result tabularx with \rowstyle]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I tried both and adapted my example to include them. They do get me nice alignment, but the '\rowstyle' command no longer works. Moveover, they complicate the code for writing the table quite a bit.

Comment: Rowstyle indeed just works. My mistake when implementing.

Answer (score 2):

The space added by `\extracolsep` is added evenly between the columns but the vertical rules are not placed in the centre of that space, but before it, so one option is simply don't use vertical rules. Alternatively `tx` or `ty` might come to your rescue:

See 
[Is it possible to make an underfull tabulary spread out?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87097/is-it-possible-to-make-an-underfull-tabulary-spread-out)

for the TY patch.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{array,tabularx,tabulary}
\newcolumntype{+}{>{\global\let\currentrowstyle\relax}}
\newcolumntype{^}{>{\currentrowstyle}}
\newcommand{\rowstyle}[1]{\gdef\currentrowstyle{#1}%
  #1\ignorespaces} 
\tymin0pt
\makeatletter


\def\foo#1\def\TY@ratio#2#3!!{
\def\TY@checkmin{#1%
 \@tempdima\TY@ratio\TY@tablewidth
 \ifdim\@tempdima>\TY@linewidth
  \advance\@tempdima-\TY@linewidth
  \Gscale@div\@tempb\@tempdima\TY@tablewidth
  \@tempdimb\TY@ratio\p@
  \advance\@tempdimb-\@tempb\p@
  \edef\TY@ratio{\strip@pt\@tempdimb}%
\fi
#3}}
\expandafter\foo\TY@checkmin!!



\makeatother

\makeatother

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\@floatboxreset{\centering\sffamily\small}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular*}{.95\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}|>{\bfseries}+l|^c|^c|}
\hline\rowstyle{\bfseries}%
    & 1   & 2 \\ \hline
a   & x   & 15\\
b   & y   & 2 \\ \hline
\end{tabular*}

\bigskip
\begin{tabular*}{.95\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}>{\bfseries}+l^c^c@{}}
\hline\rowstyle{\bfseries}%
    & 1   & 2 \\ \hline
a   & x   & 15\\
b   & y   & 2 \\ \hline
\end{tabular*}

\bigskip

\begin{tabularx}{.95\textwidth}{@{}|>{\bfseries}+l|^>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|^>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|@{}}
\hline\rowstyle{\bfseries}%
    & 1   & 2 \\ \hline
a   & x   & 15\\
b   & y   & 2 \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}

\bigskip

\begin{tabulary}{.95\textwidth}{|>{\bfseries}+L|^C|+C|}
\hline\rowstyle{\bfseries}%
    & 1   & 2 \\ \hline
a   & x   & 15\\
b   & y   & 2 \\ \hline
\end{tabulary}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```