# How to stretch Tabulary when content is smaller than the length parameter

Tags: tabulary

A coworker and I are working on templates for documentation in which certain types of tables are a repeated element. These tables vary in content depth, often wrapping the content in `Column B` of the MWE.

Because these elements repeat, we've set a consistent width for them. However, some are very short, widthwise, and do not stretch to meet the minimum width. The MWE shows this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabulary}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabulary}{0.66\textwidth}{lL}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Example A} \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}} \\
\midrule
Column A & Column B \\
\midrule
Label I & A very little bit of text.\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabulary}
\caption{Example A}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabulary}{0.66\textwidth}{lL}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Example B} \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-b}} \\
\midrule
Column A & Column B \\
\midrule
Label I & \blindtext\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabulary}
\caption{Example B}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Adding the following hack to `Example A` forces the desired width, but seems like a terrible solution: `Label I & A very little bit of text.\hspace*{50em}\\`

Certainly there is a better way to do this?

## Update

[This question regarding a similar scenario](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87097/is-it-possible-to-make-an-underfull-tabulary-spread-out) presented a patch and some helpful history regarding `tabulary`.

However, something (perhaps the images?) involved here breaks the patch suggested there, resulting in an arithmetic overflow. Manual intervention to use `tabularx` in underfull tables *is reasonable*, but not a scenario that will support automation.

Is there a way to provide arithmetic for the patch from the `\includegraphics` calls, or is this simply pushing too far into unreasonable territory?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want `tabularx`, instead?

Answer (score 2):

with `tabularx` you can fix the whole table width and `X` columns adjust their size independently from their contents.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

%\blindtext

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{.66\textwidth}{lY}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Example A} \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}} \\
\midrule
Column A & Column B \\
\midrule
Label I & A very little bit of text\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Example A}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabulary}{0.66\textwidth}{lL}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Example B} \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-b}} \\
\midrule
Column A & Column B \\
\midrule
Label I & \blindtext\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabulary}
\caption{Example B}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]