# Why is this tabulary narrower than the specified width?

Tags: spacing, tabulary

Why is this `tabulary` narrower than the specified width?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabulary}

\newcommand{\mytable}{%
    \begin{tabulary}{0.5\textwidth}{@{}L@{}}
    Text\\
    Text\\[2ex]
    \end{tabulary}%
}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

% Why are these less than 0.5\textwidth?
\mytable 
\mytable 
\mytable 
\mytable

\makebox[0.5\textwidth]{\mytable}
\makebox[0.5\textwidth]{\mytable}
\makebox[0.5\textwidth]{\mytable}
\makebox[0.5\textwidth]{\mytable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87543/1090 which has a patch, but stretching tables should  be a non-aim!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't, if you provide sufficient text to fill at least the stated width, or the column will be set at its natural width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabulary,lipsum}

\newcommand{\mytable}{%
  \begin{tabulary}{0.5\textwidth}{@{}L@{}}
  \lipsum*[2]\\
  \end{tabulary}%
}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

% Why are these less than 0.5\textwidth?

\rule{0.5\textwidth}{0.4pt}% to show the stated width

\medskip

\mytable 

\medskip

\begin{tabulary}{0.5\textwidth}{@{}|L|@{}} % add rules to show the width
text\\
\end{tabulary}

\end{document}
```

[image]