# tabu, booktabs and line spacing

Tags: line-spacing, tabu, booktabs

The following MWE illustrates the problem

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabu,blindtext}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabu} spread \linewidth {X}
test\\\midrule
Nunc quis urna dictum turpis accumsan semper.\\\midrule
\blindtext{}\\\midrule
\blindtext{}\newline{}test\\\midrule
asdg\\\midrule
\end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

The line space is not the same, if there is a linebreak in a row. I would like to have the same line space in the entire table.

[image]

Comment: the two lines you've marked aren't the only ones with uneven spacing below them.  the spacing is tight below any row that is more than one line long, and even tighter if the last line doesn't have any descenders.  (can't offer a fix, but this is a suggestion that whoever does should look at *all* the "last" lines, not just the two marked lines.)

Comment: Adding a `\strut` to the second line marked line fixes the problem. You should probably add a `\strut` to the first case as well. I am guessing that the reason it is not absolutely necessary for the first case is that the line does not span the entire width of the text.  If you add enough text before it so that it is not just a short line, then you will see the effect.

Comment: @PeterGrill, would you like to write an answer?

Comment: @PeterGrill Ping? ^^^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comments, adding a `\strut` resolves the issue:

[image]

I do not know why it is not needed for the first `test` line.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabu,blindtext}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabu} spread \linewidth {X}
test\strut\\\midrule
Nunc quis urna dictum turpis accumsan semper.\\\midrule
\blindtext{}\\\midrule
\blindtext{}\newline{}test\strut\\\midrule
asdg\\\midrule
\end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This always happens for `X` cells columns when one cell in a row has more than one line (both explicit and automatic line break). In this case, a manual strut at the end of the longest cell needs to be inserted manually or declared in the column declaration (for every `X`-column!). See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21570/strange-line-spacing-effects-in-longtabu