# How to make a given table line bold

Tags: tables, longtable, bold

Hi is it possible to make a chosen line of table (created by longtable) bold ??  I saw this question [Make first row of table all bold](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4811/make-first-row-of-table-all-bold) but the answer refers to array package. It is possible to acomplish this in longtable package ?

Comment: Duplicate of [Make first row of table all bold](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4811/make-first-row-of-table-all-bold), but it should be merged because the `tabu` answer is new and very useful.