# siunitx: protecting lines with text from being formatted as number?

Tags: tables, siunitx

The `siunitx` package has already been extremely helpful to me for formatting tables containing numbers and I now use the S-column in nearly every table of my thesis.

However there is one problem:
In the heading lines of the table (between toprule and midrule) there is text and variables and units which regularly produce errors when columns are formatted with `S[...]` so that I have to manually enclose every one of those texts with round brackets `}`.

I wonder:
Is there a way to exclude a whole tabular line from the S-column formatting and mark it as "text" (as if every cell would be written in "{}")?

Comment: Your question post seemed to have solved my problem with `siunitx`; thanks! I don't mind closing text with braces in tables with a manageable number of cells.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The TeX `\halign` primitive, from which tabulars are built, is column-oriented. As a result, row operations are not trivial to implement.  As a result, the current answer is that there is not a simple way to achieve what you'd like. I will of course consider possible approaches.

Comment: Joseph, @Martin: This reminds me on this [answer to 'How to make a given table line bold'](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22152/how-to-make-a-given-table-line-bold#question). Maybe the `\rowfont` macro can be used to insert a `\relax`? Would that be enough or does it has to be `{ }`. (This requires the `tabu` package)

Comment: @Martin: I suspect that `tabu` adds something to the end for the row, to allow a reset of 'things'. That works fine if you are happy to mess with the table mechanism, but `siunitx` avoids where possible doing anything like that.

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved with the option guard from the package tabularray. The manual provides the following example.

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{
  hlines, vlines,
  colspec={Q[si={table-format=3.2},c]Q[si={table-format=3.2},c]},
  row{1} = {guard}
}
   Head  & Head   \\
  111    & 111    \\
    2.1  &   2.2  \\
   33.11 &  33.22 \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image: example]