# Align first row of a table differently then subsequent rows

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

For example, is it possible to justify the first row of a table differently from the rest? Maybe there is a way to combine two tables to look like one? MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{| c | c | c | c |}
    \hline
    & \textbf{S1} & \textbf{S2} & \textbf{S3} \\
    \hline
    \textbf{D1} & 4217 & 5821 & 1102 \\
    \textbf{D2} & 3679 & 5089 & 991 \\
    \textbf{D3} & 2589 & 3301 & 604 \\
    \textbf{D4} & 1418 & 1722 & 294 \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! The short answer to both of your questions is: "Yes." Please consider adding a minimum working example (MWE) of the `tabular` environment you have in mind. Without such information, it's going to be very difficult to provide more specific suggestions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The standard way to justify the heading rows of a small table is to use the `\multicolumn` command, which allows you to override the column specification for each span of rows.  In this example, I've used the `booktabs` package, which is highly recommended for any professional looking table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lrp{1in}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{A} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{B} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{C}\\
\midrule
left & right & 1 inch\\
l & r & foo\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

For some fancier ideas for heading rows, see [Make first row of table all bold](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4811/2693).

Comment: Would that be a ISO standard, or IEEE standard, or...? `;-)`

Answer (score 5):

This is a slightly different approach to what is posted in [Make first row of table all bold](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4811/5764).

`tabular` environments are *easily* formatted column-wise. Not so much row-wise. However, there are ways around it. Here's one attempt.

You can use an `\if...` conditional to distinguish between your header/non-header rows. `\newif\headerrow` defines the condition `\ifheaderrow` that can be either true (`\headerrowtrue`) or false (`\headerrowfalse`). Subsequently you can insert contents before each table entry depending on this condition with the aid of the [`array` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/array):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/array
\newif\ifheaderrow
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\ifheaderrow\bfseries\fi}c}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \global\headerrowtrue
  \begin{tabular}{|>{\bfseries}c | *{3}{C|}}
    \hline
    & S1 & S2 & S3 \\ 
    \hline \global\headerrowfalse
     D1 & 4217 & 5821 & 1102 \\
    D2 & 3679 & 5089 & 991 \\
    D3 & 2589 & 3301 & 604 \\
    D4 & 1418 & 1722 & 294 \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}​
```

The resetting of `\headerrowfalse` must be made `\global`, since the modification would otherwise only hold within the group, which is the cell within which it is called.

Comment: I like it, but is it just me or does this seem hackish (like a lot of LaTeX I see)? Maybe it's just me being new to LaTeX.

Comment: @Jeff: Perhaps, but "hackish" may be a very subjective term. There's also the [`tabu` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabu) which make the above perhaps look a little less "hackish."

Comment: @Werner Very useful solution for formatting rows. Nice!

Answer (score 0):

after eleven years ...

- by use of the `makecell` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,
            makecell} % for `thead` command
\renewcommand\theadfont{}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lrp{1in}}
\toprule
\thead{A} & \thead{B} & \thead{C}\\
\midrule
left & right & 1 inch\\
l & r & foo\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,
            makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lrp{1in}}
\toprule
\thead{A} & \thead{B} & \thead{C}\\
\midrule
left & right & 1 inch\\
l & r & foo\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

- today someone my consider novel table package `tabularray`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {l r Q[l, wd=1in]},
             row{1} = {c, font=\bfseries}
             }
    \toprule
A       & B     & C         \\
    \midrule
left    & right & 1 inch    \\
l       & r     & foo       \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

result is the same as in the second example.