# tabularx and formatting entire column

Tags: tables, arrays, tabularx

This is obliquely related to [this query](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/75442/8863), except that I would like to have a `tabularx` environment where the entire first *column* is in italics (or some other standard formatting). The following obviously does not work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\em}X{}<XX}
a & a & a \\
b & b & b
\end{tabularx} 
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I do actually need `tabularx` since I expect the last column to contain quite long sentences.

Comment: answer already given but your code would have worked apart from `{}<` which should be omitted or should be `<{}` (Using `\itshape` is most likely more semantically correct than using `\em` but it would have worked)

Comment: Thanks David. I thought that this feature was not allowed with `tabularx`, not noticing that I was making a typo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `{>{\itshape\arraybackslash}XXX}` works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\itshape\arraybackslash}XXX}
a & a & a \\
b & b & b
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]