# Format whole row of table as bold

Tags: tables, formatting, bold

This appears to be a problem which a few people have had before, but since I've been unable to find a solution which works I thought I should ask again.

I have a LaTeX table of 5 columns width and about 100 rows depth, and I'd like to format whole rows in bold font as opposed to changing each individual cell entry to bold. I don't want every single row to be bold, only a certain selection.

I've tried this solution:

[Make first row of table all bold](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4811/make-first-row-of-table-all-bold)

This doesn't throw up errors, but only changes the first entry of the row to bold font, rather than all the entries in the row. My code is below.

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{List of the gamma rays from TS1 and TS2 in the energy region from 140 keV to 655 keV}
\begin{adjustbox}{center}
\begin{tabular}{cccrcc}
\toprule
Energy & Energy & Origin & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Branching} & Av. peak  & Av. Peak \\

Measured & Measured & \&    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Ratio } & count rate in & count rate \\
TS1   & TS2   & Process & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(emission} & TS1 [1/hr]  & TS2  \\
 (keV) & (keV) &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{probability} & Beam on  & [1/hr]  \\
      &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{per decay)} & (Beam off) &  \\
      \midrule
140.38 & 140.31 & 75m-Ge (IT) & 39\%  & 461 (0) & 17 \\
159.70 & --    & 63-Cu (n,G) & 15.00\% & 411 (0) & -- \\
175.77 & --    & 70-Ge (n,G) & 25.00\% & 272 (0) & -- \\
186.39 & 186.59 & 235-U (A) & 57.20\% & 44 (56) & 43 \\
199.02 & 199.07 & 71-Ge (EC) & N/A   & 440 (0) & 38 \\
239.20 & 239.19 & 212-Pb (B-) & 43.30\% & 192 (197) & 186 \\
242.41 & 242.59 & 214-Pb (B-) & 7.43\% & 52 (57) & 79 \\
250.75 & --    & 39-Cl (B-) & 46.30\% & 177 (0) & -- \\
--    & 272.36 & 173-Lu (EC) & 21.20\% & --    & 48 \\
278.51 & --    & 63-Cu (n,G) & 24.00\% & 296 (0) & -- \\
295.65 & 295.55 & 214-Pb (B-) & 19.30\% & 92 (133) & 134 \\
320.41 & --    & 51-Cr (EC) & 10.00\% & 16 (17) & -- \\
338.61 & 338.78 & 228-Ac (B-) & 11.27\% & 43 (41) & 50 \\
352.28 & 352.22 & 214-Pb (B-) & 19.30\% & 449 (232) & 307 \\
352.28 & 352.22 & 56-Fe (n,G) & 9.50\% & 449 (232) & 307 \\
440.09 & --    & 23-Mg (EC) & 8.20\% & 131 (0) & -- \\
463.21 & 463.31 & 228-Ac (B-) & 4.40\% & 25 (17) & 14 \\
472.27 & --    & 23-Na (n,G) & 90.39\% & 81 (0) & -- \\
477.77 & --    & 7-Be (EC) & 10.52\% & 1457 (1501) & -- \\
500.01 & --    & 70-Gen (n,G) & 24.10\% & 93 (0) & -- \\
510.99 & 511.02 & Ann.  & N/A   & 116190 (262) & 18607 \\
--    & 558.42 & 113-Cd (n,G) & 74.40\% & --    & 141 \\
583.45 & 583.31 & 208-Tl (B-) & 84.50\% & 82 (91) & 84 \\
595.96 & 596.31 & 74-Ge (n,n' G) & 100.00\% & 272(0) & 15 \\
609.26 & --    & 74-Ge (n,n' G) & 18.20\% & 275 (219) & -- \\
609.48 & 609.55 & 214-Bi (B-) & 46.10\% & 275 (219) & 287 \\
--    & 651.28 & 113-Cd (n,G) & 14.09\% & --    & 35 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
\end{adjustbox}
\label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
```

Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 26):

Maybe this?  I introduce a `\setrow{...}` macro invoked on the first element of a row, which applies to each cell of that row (and is then reset).  It employs the `>{}` and `<{}` feature of `tabularx`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcommand\setrow[1]{\gdef\rowmac{#1}#1\ignorespaces}
\newcommand\clearrow{\global\let\rowmac\relax}
\clearrow
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{>{\rowmac}c|>{\rowmac}c|>{\rowmac}c<{\clearrow}}
a & b & c\\
\setrow{\bfseries}d & e & f\\
e & f& g\\
h & i & j\\
\setrow{\itshape} k & l & m\\
n & o & p
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As applied to the OP's problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,adjustbox,booktabs}
\newcommand\setrow[1]{\gdef\rowmac{#1}#1\ignorespaces}
\newcommand\clearrow{\global\let\rowmac\relax}
\clearrow
\begin{document}
\begin{adjustbox}{center}
\begin{tabular}{>{\rowmac}c>{\rowmac}c>{\rowmac}c>{\rowmac}r>{\rowmac}c>{\rowmac}%
  c<{\clearrow}}
\toprule
Energy & Energy & Origin & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Branching} & Av. peak  & Av. Peak \\

Measured & Measured & \&    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Ratio } & count rate in & count rate \\
TS1   & TS2   & Process & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(emission} & TS1 [1/hr]  & TS2  \\
 (keV) & (keV) &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{probability} & Beam on  & [1/hr]  \\
      &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{per decay)} & (Beam off) &  \\
      \midrule
140.38 & 140.31 & 75m-Ge (IT) & 39\%  & 461 (0) & 17 \\
159.70 & --    & 63-Cu (n,G) & 15.00\% & 411 (0) & -- \\
175.77 & --    & 70-Ge (n,G) & 25.00\% & 272 (0) & -- \\
\setrow{\bfseries}186.39 & 186.59 & 235-U (A) & 57.20\% & 44 (56) & 43 \\
199.02 & 199.07 & 71-Ge (EC) & N/A   & 440 (0) & 38 \\
239.20 & 239.19 & 212-Pb (B-) & 43.30\% & 192 (197) & 186 \\
242.41 & 242.59 & 214-Pb (B-) & 7.43\% & 52 (57) & 79 \\
250.75 & --    & 39-Cl (B-) & 46.30\% & 177 (0) & -- \\
--    & 272.36 & 173-Lu (EC) & 21.20\% & --    & 48 \\
\setrow{\bfseries}278.51 & --    & 63-Cu (n,G) & 24.00\% & 296 (0) & -- \\
\setrow{\bfseries}295.65 & 295.55 & 214-Pb (B-) & 19.30\% & 92 (133) & 134 \\
320.41 & --    & 51-Cr (EC) & 10.00\% & 16 (17) & -- \\
338.61 & 338.78 & 228-Ac (B-) & 11.27\% & 43 (41) & 50 \\
352.28 & 352.22 & 214-Pb (B-) & 19.30\% & 449 (232) & 307 \\
352.28 & 352.22 & 56-Fe (n,G) & 9.50\% & 449 (232) & 307 \\
440.09 & --    & 23-Mg (EC) & 8.20\% & 131 (0) & -- \\
463.21 & 463.31 & 228-Ac (B-) & 4.40\% & 25 (17) & 14 \\
\setrow{\bfseries}472.27 & --    & 23-Na (n,G) & 90.39\% & 81 (0) & -- \\
477.77 & --    & 7-Be (EC) & 10.52\% & 1457 (1501) & -- \\
500.01 & --    & 70-Gen (n,G) & 24.10\% & 93 (0) & -- \\
510.99 & 511.02 & Ann.  & N/A   & 116190 (262) & 18607 \\
--    & 558.42 & 113-Cd (n,G) & 74.40\% & --    & 141 \\
\setrow{\bfseries}583.45 & 583.31 & 208-Tl (B-) & 84.50\% & 82 (91) & 84 \\
595.96 & 596.31 & 74-Ge (n,n' G) & 100.00\% & 272(0) & 15 \\
\setrow{\bfseries}609.26 & --    & 74-Ge (n,n' G) & 18.20\% & 275 (219) & -- \\
609.48 & 609.55 & 214-Bi (B-) & 46.10\% & 275 (219) & 287 \\
--    & 651.28 & 113-Cd (n,G) & 14.09\% & --    & 35 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
\end{adjustbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Terrific. Question answered and problem solved.

Comment: @MattS I am adding `\ignorespaces` as part of the close of `\setrow`, to remove a spurious space.

Comment: What's the point of `\clearrow`

Comment: @theonlygusti It turns it off at the end of a row, to avoid affecting the next row.

Answer (score 4):

The first answer to the question you linked in your question (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4816/36296) seems to work just fine. If only the first entry was coloured, did you remember to adjust the alignment options to `$c^c^c^r^c^c`?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{$}{>{\global\let\currentrowstyle\relax}}
\newcolumntype{^}{>{\currentrowstyle}}
\newcommand{\rowstyle}[1]{\gdef\currentrowstyle{#1}%
    #1\ignorespaces
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \caption{List of the gamma rays from TS1 and TS2 in the energy region from 140 keV to 655 keV}
    \begin{adjustbox}{center}
        \begin{tabular}{$c^c^c^r^c^c}
            \toprule
            \rowstyle{\bfseries}
            Energy & Energy & Origin & \multicolumn{1}{^c}{Branching} & Av. peak  & Av. Peak \\

            \rowstyle{\bfseries}Measured & Measured & \&    & \multicolumn{1}{^c}{Ratio } & count rate in & count rate \\
            \rowstyle{\bfseries}TS1   & TS2   & Process & \multicolumn{1}{^c}{(emission} & TS1 [1/hr]  & TS2  \\
            \rowstyle{\bfseries}(keV) & (keV) &       & \multicolumn{1}{^c}{probability} & Beam on  & [1/hr]  \\
            \rowstyle{\bfseries}&       &       & \multicolumn{1}{^c}{per decay)} & (Beam off) &  \\
            \midrule
            140.38 & 140.31 & 75m-Ge (IT) & 39\%  & 461 (0) & 17 \\
            159.70 & --    & 63-Cu (n,G) & 15.00\% & 411 (0) & -- \\
            175.77 & --    & 70-Ge (n,G) & 25.00\% & 272 (0) & -- \\
            186.39 & 186.59 & 235-U (A) & 57.20\% & 44 (56) & 43 \\
            199.02 & 199.07 & 71-Ge (EC) & N/A   & 440 (0) & 38 \\
            239.20 & 239.19 & 212-Pb (B-) & 43.30\% & 192 (197) & 186 \\
            242.41 & 242.59 & 214-Pb (B-) & 7.43\% & 52 (57) & 79 \\
            \rowstyle{\bfseries}250.75 & --    & 39-Cl (B-) & 46.30\% & 177 (0) & -- \\
            --    & 272.36 & 173-Lu (EC) & 21.20\% & --    & 48 \\
            278.51 & --    & 63-Cu (n,G) & 24.00\% & 296 (0) & -- \\
            295.65 & 295.55 & 214-Pb (B-) & 19.30\% & 92 (133) & 134 \\
            320.41 & --    & 51-Cr (EC) & 10.00\% & 16 (17) & -- \\
            338.61 & 338.78 & 228-Ac (B-) & 11.27\% & 43 (41) & 50 \\
            352.28 & 352.22 & 214-Pb (B-) & 19.30\% & 449 (232) & 307 \\
            352.28 & 352.22 & 56-Fe (n,G) & 9.50\% & 449 (232) & 307 \\
            440.09 & --    & 23-Mg (EC) & 8.20\% & 131 (0) & -- \\
            463.21 & 463.31 & 228-Ac (B-) & 4.40\% & 25 (17) & 14 \\
            472.27 & --    & 23-Na (n,G) & 90.39\% & 81 (0) & -- \\
            477.77 & --    & 7-Be (EC) & 10.52\% & 1457 (1501) & -- \\
            500.01 & --    & 70-Gen (n,G) & 24.10\% & 93 (0) & -- \\
            510.99 & 511.02 & Ann.  & N/A   & 116190 (262) & 18607 \\
            --    & 558.42 & 113-Cd (n,G) & 74.40\% & --    & 141 \\
            583.45 & 583.31 & 208-Tl (B-) & 84.50\% & 82 (91) & 84 \\
            595.96 & 596.31 & 74-Ge (n,n' G) & 100.00\% & 272(0) & 15 \\
            609.26 & --    & 74-Ge (n,n' G) & 18.20\% & 275 (219) & -- \\
            609.48 & 609.55 & 214-Bi (B-) & 46.10\% & 275 (219) & 287 \\
            --    & 651.28 & 113-Cd (n,G) & 14.09\% & --    & 35 \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}%
    \end{adjustbox}
    \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The environment `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` has a built-in command `\RowStyle` to specify formatting instructions to the (end of the) current row.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{adjustbox}{center}
\begin{NiceTabular}{cccrcc}
\toprule
Energy & Energy & Origin & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Branching} & Av. peak  & Av. Peak \\

Measured & Measured & \&    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Ratio } & count rate in & count rate \\
TS1   & TS2   & Process & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(emission} & TS1 [1/hr]  & TS2  \\
 (keV) & (keV) &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{probability} & Beam on  & [1/hr]  \\
      &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{per decay)} & (Beam off) &  \\
      \midrule
140.38 & 140.31 & 75m-Ge (IT) & 39\%  & 461 (0) & 17 \\
159.70 & --    & 63-Cu (n,G) & 15.00\% & 411 (0) & -- \\
175.77 & --    & 70-Ge (n,G) & 25.00\% & 272 (0) & -- \\
\RowStyle{\bfseries}186.39 & 186.59 & 235-U (A) & 57.20\% & 44 (56) & 43 \\
199.02 & 199.07 & 71-Ge (EC) & N/A   & 440 (0) & 38 \\
239.20 & 239.19 & 212-Pb (B-) & 43.30\% & 192 (197) & 186 \\
242.41 & 242.59 & 214-Pb (B-) & 7.43\% & 52 (57) & 79 \\
250.75 & --    & 39-Cl (B-) & 46.30\% & 177 (0) & -- \\
--    & 272.36 & 173-Lu (EC) & 21.20\% & --    & 48 \\
\RowStyle{\bfseries}278.51 & --    & 63-Cu (n,G) & 24.00\% & 296 (0) & -- \\
\RowStyle{\bfseries}295.65 & 295.55 & 214-Pb (B-) & 19.30\% & 92 (133) & 134 \\
320.41 & --    & 51-Cr (EC) & 10.00\% & 16 (17) & -- \\
338.61 & 338.78 & 228-Ac (B-) & 11.27\% & 43 (41) & 50 \\
352.28 & 352.22 & 214-Pb (B-) & 19.30\% & 449 (232) & 307 \\
352.28 & 352.22 & 56-Fe (n,G) & 9.50\% & 449 (232) & 307 \\
440.09 & --    & 23-Mg (EC) & 8.20\% & 131 (0) & -- \\
463.21 & 463.31 & 228-Ac (B-) & 4.40\% & 25 (17) & 14 \\
\RowStyle{\bfseries}472.27 & --    & 23-Na (n,G) & 90.39\% & 81 (0) & -- \\
477.77 & --    & 7-Be (EC) & 10.52\% & 1457 (1501) & -- \\
500.01 & --    & 70-Gen (n,G) & 24.10\% & 93 (0) & -- \\
510.99 & 511.02 & Ann.  & N/A   & 116190 (262) & 18607 \\
--    & 558.42 & 113-Cd (n,G) & 74.40\% & --    & 141 \\
\RowStyle{\bfseries}583.45 & 583.31 & 208-Tl (B-) & 84.50\% & 82 (91) & 84 \\
595.96 & 596.31 & 74-Ge (n,n' G) & 100.00\% & 272(0) & 15 \\
\RowStyle{\bfseries}609.26 & --    & 74-Ge (n,n' G) & 18.20\% & 275 (219) & -- \\
609.48 & 609.55 & 214-Bi (B-) & 46.10\% & 275 (219) & 287 \\
--    & 651.28 & 113-Cd (n,G) & 14.09\% & --    & 35 \\
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}%
\end{adjustbox}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]