# How to Make first Row and its Math Symbols of table all Bold?

Tags: tables, formatting, amsmath, bold

Commented code generates Fig. 2, while active code generates the wanted output in Fig. 1

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}    
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4816/13173
%\begin{table}
%\begin{tabular}{| +p{3cm} | ^p{3cm} | }
%\rowstyle{\bfseries}
%Count \texorpdfstring{$P_{st}(G)$} & Hello \\ \hline
% Output: wrong

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{| p{3cm} | p{3cm} | }
% Output: ok but not generic
\hline
\textbf{Count \texorpdfstring{$P_{st}(G)$}} & \textbf{Hello} \\ \hline
1           & 2 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Fig. 1 Wanted output (done with `\textbf`), Fig. 2 Output of the `\bfseries` approach with Math symbols

[image]
[image]

System: Linux Ubuntu 16.04
TexLive: 2015

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you replace

```
\textbf{Count \texorpdfstring{$P_{st}(G)$}}
```

with

```
\bfseries\mathversion{bold} Count \texorpdfstring{$P_{st}(G)$}{}
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you use `\mathversion{bold}` instead of `\boldmath`? It sounds me more stable but not sure.

Comment: @Masi - The LaTeX kernel -- see line 3776 in the current version of the file `latex.ltx` -- defines `\boldmath` (essentially) as `\mathversion{bold}`.

Answer (score 1):

Both ways work adding `\boldmath`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{+}{>{\global\let\currentrowstyle\relax}}
\newcolumntype{^}{>{\currentrowstyle}}
\newcommand{\rowstyle}[1]{\gdef\currentrowstyle{#1}%
  #1\ignorespaces
}
\usepackage{hyperref}

 \begin{document}
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4816/13173
\begin{table}[!htb]
\begin{tabular}{| +p{3cm} | ^p{3cm} | }
\hline
\rowstyle{\bfseries\boldmath}
Count \texorpdfstring{$P_{st}(G)$} & Hello \\ \hline
1 & 2 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!htb]
\begin{tabular}{| p{3cm} | p{3cm} | }
\hline
\textbf{\boldmath Count \texorpdfstring{$P_{st}(G)$}} & \textbf{Hello} \\ \hline
1 & 2 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is `\boldmath` the same as `\mathversion{bold}`?

Comment: As far as I know, yes. It's shorter. My main point was to show that `\rowstyle` works.