# \bfseries for math mode (whole table row in bold)

Tags: tables, bold, boldmath

I've got this neat little snippet from question [Make first row of table all bold](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4811/make-first-row-of-table-all-bold/4816#4816):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{$}{>{\global\let\currentrowstyle\relax}}
\newcolumntype{^}{>{\currentrowstyle}}
\newcommand{\rowstyle}[1]{\gdef\currentrowstyle{#1}%
  #1\ignorespaces
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{$l^c^r}
\rowstyle{\bfseries}
a & a & a \\
b & b & b \\
c & c & c \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

It works perfectly fine in text mode.
However, if I've got a math mode in my table like in the following snippet, this won't work.

```
\begin{tabular}{$l^c^r}
\rowstyle{\bfseries}
a & $1.33*10^5$ & a \\
b & b           & b \\
c & c           & c \\
\end{tabular}
```

The two a are bold, but the equation isn't bold.
However if I'm using

```
\begin{tabular}{$l^c^r}
\rowstyle{\bfseries}
a & \textbf{$1.33*10^5$} & a \\
b & b                    & b \\
c & c                    & c \\
\end{tabular}
```

the equation is rendered bold just perfectly.
Do I need another command for this to work?
I've trying to typeset one row with ~17 columns (12 math mode) bold in about 20 tables. I would really like not to put every equation in a \textbf.

---

Using

```
\begin{tabular}{$l^c^r}
\rowstyle{\textbf}
a & $1.33*10^5$ & a \\
b & b           & b \\
c & c           & c \\
\end{tabular}
```

Ends in an error `` You can't use a prefix with `\aftergroup' `` in the next line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That was quick, I am a dimwit.
The solution is to add `\boldmath`:

```
\begin{tabular}{$l^c^r}
\rowstyle{\boldmath\textbf}
a & $1.33*10^5$ & a \\
b & b           & b \\
c & c           & c \\
\end{tabular}
```