# How to get the bold math to work with `code-for-first-row` in `NiceMatrix`?

Tags: math-mode, nicematrix

I want to get the first row to be bold as follows

[image]

The answer in [\bfseries for math mode (whole table row in bold)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/397042/bfseries-for-math-mode-whole-table-row-in-bold) suggests `\rowstyle{\boldmath\textbf}` for `tabular` which seems to work well. However, `\RowStyle` and `code-for-first-row` from `NiceMatrix` do not seem to work well with `\boldmath\textbf` unless these commands are placed before each entry in the table. Also, such solution does not work for `\text` which we use to place text in math mode. Is it possible to get a neat solution?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
        
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \begin{NiceArray}{l l l}[first-row, code-for-first-row=]
        
        \text{\textbf{Item No}} & \boldmath\textbf f(t) & \boldmath\textbf F(s)
        \\
        
        1. & \delta(t) & 1
        \\
        
    \end{NiceArray}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd say `\mbox{\boldmath$f(t)$}` or `\bm{f(t)}` with `\usepackage{bm}`.

Comment: Unrelated, any reason why the majority of your questions have no accepted answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `{NiceArray}` (and the similar environments such as `{pNiceArray}`), the tokens corresponding to the key `code-for-first-row` are inserted after the `$` which starts math mode in the cell. But you can exit the math mode with the first symbol `$`, put whatever instructions you want (such as `\bfseries`) and start math mode once again with another symbol `$`.

```
code-for-first-row = $\bfseries\mathversion{bold}$
```

Despite the appearances, the tokens between the symbols `$` will not be in math mode!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
        
\begin{document}

$\begin{pNiceArray}{ccc}[first-row,code-for-first-row=$\bfseries\mathversion{bold}$]
\text{Text} & a+b & c+d \\ 
1 & a+b & c+d \\ 
2 & a+b & c+d \\ 
\end{pNiceArray}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

If you want to set `code-for-first-row` with `\NiceMatrixOptions`, you should test for math mode in order to have the code valid in all the environments of `nicematrix`.

```
\NiceMatrixOptions
  {
    code-for-first-row = 
     \ifmmode $\bfseries\mathversion{bold}$
     \else \bfseries\mathversion{bold}
     \fi
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In recent versions of `nicematrix` (≥ 6.3 of 2021-10-18), you can use the commande `\RowStyle` and its key `bold`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
        
\begin{document}

\NiceMatrixOptions{code-for-first-row= \RowStyle[bold]{}}

$\begin{pNiceArray}{ccc}[first-row]
\text{Text} & a+b & c+d \\ 
1 & a+b & c+d \\ 
2 & a+b & c+d \\ 
\end{pNiceArray}$

\end{document}
```

As usual with `nicematrix`, you need several compilations.

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: I would have made an edit to the existing answer.

Comment: Is it possible to have something like "code for each cell", not only first one? I could have defined a new column type, but for `NiceMatrix` amount of of columns is arbitrary and changes by adding\removing `&`.

Comment: @antshar: With the latest version of `nicematrix` (v 6.11 of 2022-07-16), there is a key `matrix/columns-type` available in `\NiceMatrixOptions` to fix the default column type used by `{pNiceMatrix}`, `{bNiceMatrix}`, etc.

Comment: @F.Pantigny thanks!