# Rowstyle in xltabular

Tags: tables, longtable, tabularx, xltabular

I'm creating a `newenvironment` for my standard style of table, using xltabular (tabularx + longtable). Something like this:

```
\newenvironment{tab1}[3]{\xltabular{\textwidth}{#2}
\hline
\rowcolor{WB7} #3 \\
\hline
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{#1}{c}{\color{Y1} \faArrowUp \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad \faArrowUp \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad \faArrowUp \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad \faArrowUp \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad \faArrowUp} \\
\hline
\rowcolor{WB7} #3 \\
\hline
\endhead
\multicolumn{#1}{c}{\color{Y1} \faArrowDown \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad \faArrowDown \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad \faArrowDown \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad \faArrowDown \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad \faArrowDown}
\endfoot
\hline
\endlastfoot
}{\endxltabular}

\begin{tab1}{3}{|C|F|C|}{HELLO & Hello & hello}
    1 & 2 & 3
\end{tab1}
```

The idea is that every table has a heading (#3) which will appear again in the case the table needs another page. This environment needs the number of columns (#1), the type of columns (#2) and the heading (#3), but for the heading I want a concrete style, a `\cellcolor{WB7}` and a rowstyle of `\bfseries`. Using `\rowcolor{WB7}` works fine, but I couldn't find any way to change the rowstyle. I just found these 2 questions which don't work in `xltabular`:

[Make first row of table all bold](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4811/make-first-row-of-table-all-bold/4816#4816)

[\bfseries for math mode (whole table row in bold)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/397042/bfseries-for-math-mode-whole-table-row-in-bold)

Of course I could do `{\textbf{HELLO} & \textbf{Hello} & \textbf{hello}}` but as you can notice this is not a clean solution and it would be tedious to type `\textbf{}` every time.

**CODE FOR COMPILING (simplified)**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}

\newenvironment{tab}[3]{\xltabular{\textwidth}{#2}
\hline
\rowcolor{yellow} #3 \\
\hline
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{#1}{c}{$\Uparrow$} \\
\hline
\rowcolor{yellow} #3 \\
\hline
\endhead
\multicolumn{#1}{c}{$\Downarrow$}
\endfoot
\hline
\endlastfoot
}{\endxltabular}

\begin{tab}{3}{|X|X|X|}{HELLO & Hello & hello}
    1 & 2 & 3
\end{tab}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Why not using [package `tabularray`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularray), which does, e.g., provide defining the style of each row by row number.

Comment: I'm currently trying with `\SetRow{font=\bfseries}` but it is not changing anything. I'm looking at the documentation of tabularray and also have tried to `row{1}{font=\bfseries}` but I don't know where to put this command as this is a `xltabular` environment and not a `tblr`.